# IIS Orphaned Requests

Tags: debugging, iis, iis-7, asp-classic, w3wp

We have IIS 7 running a Classic ASP app and I've been noticing the following issue lately. Over the course of the day, if I look at Server Node --> Worker Processes some requests seem to fill up there. The elapsed time is something crazy like 12 hours at the end of the day. This requests all sit in the ExecuteRequestHandler stage.

There is no way anything is executing for that long, and I cannot seem to reproduce the issue. I have tried dumping w3wp.exe, using FRT, and all that good stuff, but I have some *general* questions:

1. Is there a setting that controls WHEN IIS stops a request? To be specific, in development, if I purposely design a page to be slow (i.e. update a SQL table thats locked) and then CLOSE out of browser,  and monitor the requests in IIS, I see that the request still sits there for about 20 seconds before being removed. Is that 20 seconds a random interval, or can that be SET somewhere? To be clear, it's not that the page takes 20 seconds to execute, it will execute forever (in this test case) but it seems IIS gives up on it after 20 or so seconds after I log out.
2. Is there some way to see "orphaned" requests, I.E. requests in the app pool that nobody is waiting for anymore
3. What else can I do to try and debug this? A dump of w3wp says there are client connections with an HTTP request state of HTR_READING_CLIENT_REQUEST.
4. I keep getting suggestions of modifying IIS config settings such as AspRequestQueueMax, every time I try looking those up in the ApplicationHost.config I don't see those items set, so either I'm looking at the wrong place, or a default value would not be explicitly set in the config. This begs 2 questions: a) How do you READ these config values, i.e. get current value, b) how do you SET these.

Comment: In case anybody stumbles across this, the answer to #4 is that if it's not in the config, it relies on the default, and many of the settings are in IIS itself. For queuemax, you set this at the server node --> asp --> "limits properties" section, same for threads per processor which is another setting I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A Classic ASP request will keep running until the script timeout is reached, regardless of whether the client is connected or not. I believe the default is 90 seconds, but an .ASP file can override this by setting the Server.ScriptTimeout property directly (which is pretty common). If your request queue is filling up then this is likely the reason and changing the defaults will not help.

If you can edit the ASP code, you can add logic like this in potentially long running sections:

```
If Not Response.IsClientConnected Then Call Response.End()
```

You can also global search your code for Server.ScriptTimeout to understand from where the abuse is coming.

If you do want to change the default script timeout, here is where it is stored:
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/limits

To change via the IIS7 GUI go to: (web site) > (features view) > ("IIS" category) > "ASP" > expand "Limits Properties" node > "Script Time-out"

Comment: Thanks, this gives me something to work with.
For the Response.IsClientConnected, how can that work? If the code is on line, say, 1200, and there's something long running there, how will it ever get to line 1201 to execute that condition? And if it CAN get to line 1201, then it isn't stuck. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Shalom: generally the trick is to find spots low enough in the code that each "line" is a short running task. Sometimes you may have to redesign a bit. For example; if you have one line that copies 1000 files and returns. You may need to rewrite that code to copy a single file at a time in a loop. Then you can add the IsCliientConnected in that loop.